# Getting connect ETIMEDOUT when trying to install a VSCODE extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

When trying to install a VSCODE extension from the marketplace, I'm getting connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 possibly due to company firewall restrictions.

Is there a way to download and install extensions from a local drive? I couldn't find a "download" option on the VSCODE marketplace.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add your corporate proxy to VSCode settings.

**Step 1.** 
Open File > Preferences > User Settings

**Step 2.**

Copy and Paste below into the settings.json (file that opens) make sure is inside the curly brackets {}

```
//-------- HTTP configuration --------

// The proxy setting to use. If not set will be taken from the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables
"http.proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8080", //your corporate proxy

// Whether the proxy server certificate should be verified against the list of supplied CAs.
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

**Step 3.**
Press F1 and type Reload Window and press enter to refresh.

> Tip: if you don't know your corporate proxy settings, follow this
>   advice:
>   https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using

Comment: Mac users... the user settings is under Code > Preferences > User Settings.

Comment: Step 3 is crucial. I spent 2.5 hours trying to figure out why my proxy wasn't working for an extension in VS Code and pressing F1 and rerunning a command (for the extension) fixed my issue it appears. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you can do.

Most extensions are in public repos. Click Getting Started on the side panel.

[image]

Download the code from the public repo.

Follow the instructions in the [docs](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/install-extension) to side load the application.

> If you want to share your extension or customization with others
>   privately, you can simply send them a copy of the output from the
>   generator and ask them to add it under their .vscode/extensions
>   folder. Alternatively, package your extension using the vsce
>   publishing tool and send them the .vsix file.

Comment: I was trying to get the .vsix file to install the **C#** extension from GitHub. The hint in this answer to use the link under "Resources" got me to the GitHub page but I then had to navigate to the **Code** tab and click on the **Releases** link, which took to me to https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases. From there I downloaded the .vsix file and installed via VSC menu File -> Open File.

Answer (score 5):

Add proxy configuration to VS Code

1. Open VS Code as Administrator
2. Open File > Preferences > User Settings
3. Add following configuration to the open file.

```
{
  "http.proxy": "http://userName:password@companyProxyURL:portNumber",
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the "userName:password@" tip, that's just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. VS Code clearly not talking to extension server.

```
code --install-extension <extension>
```

gave a time-out message.

Turned out that I had bogus settings of HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY. Unset the environment variables and VS Code worked beautifully.