# Setting Corporate network proxy in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, force.com

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio Code IDE for Salesforce development. The IDE works fine in my personal network, where I can retrieve and upload the metadata file without any issue. When I connect to my office network I'm not able to do the same.The Salesforce CLI shows the following error while retrieving the metadata -

**"error: connect etimedout 85.224.145.196:443"**

Later I got to know that I will have to set up the network proxy in VS Code. I have gone through the following links and tried to add the proxy to the 
VS code. Unfortunately, nothing worked for me -
[Getting connect ETIMEDOUT when trying to install a VSCODE extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426154/getting-connect-etimedout-when-trying-to-install-a-vscode-extension)
http://www.niranjankala.in/post/How-to-setup-Proxy-settings-in-Visual-Studio-Code

I used to set the proxy in eclipse in this way-
Preference >> Network connection >> Proxy entries -
Schema: "HTTP" ,Host:Proxy URL of the company,Port:8080,Auth:"No" AND Proxy Bypass - Host:127.0.0.1, Provider:Manual

If somebody faced this before request you to share the way to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730040/how-to-specify-a-user-id-and-password-for-visual-studio-code-with-an-authenticat) - the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730040/how-to-specify-a-user-id-and-password-for-visual-studio-code-with-an-authenticat)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify a user id and password for Visual Studio Code with an authenticating proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730040/how-to-specify-a-user-id-and-password-for-visual-studio-code-with-an-authenticat)